# Using indentation to automatically begin and end itemize environments

Tags: macros, lists, indentation, itemize, catcodes

This is a question one might answer with "Why the hell would you want to do it?!", sort of an experiment.

What I am looking for is a way to write lists with many levels of nestings (notes for school) in a "natural" way. Previously, I used an elaborate system of Pandoc, LaTeX and Makefiles to generate notes with occasional LaTeX snippets, however, I would like a more integrated workflow (for example, embedding pseudocode in a codebox environment in a Pandoc/Markdown file is quite challenging, as Markdown was designed with HTML in mind).

If I make `+` an active character, like

```
\makeatletter
\mathchardef\@my@mathplus=\mathcode`+
\catcode`+=\active
\def{+}{\ifmmode\@my@mathplus\else\item\fi}
\mateatother
```

I can write itemizes like

```
\begin{itemize}
+ one
+ two
+ three
\end{itemize}
```

however, I would like to get rid of `\begin{itemize}` and `\end{itemize}` and write notes like

```
+ one
    + subitem one
    + subitem two
+ two
+ three
```

resulting in the nested list, neatly rendered.

Is there a way to achieve this, or I should consider some kind of pre-procession instead? (Creative and mildly insane answers are appreciated.)

Comment: Two comments. (1) It's `\def+`, not `\def{+}`. (2) It should better be `\DeclareRobustCommand+{\ifmmode\@my@mathplus\else\expandafter\item\fi}`; apart from robustness, you can write `+[label]` as you would with `\item[label]`. Such shortcuts, however, make the document hard to read and unstructured.

Comment: @egreg I didn't really aim for robustness, just a dirty proof of concept. Although thanks for pointing out the mistake with my code (I didn't copy and paste from my text editor but typed it again by hand... my bad).

Comment: ConTeXt can process markdown input directly.

Comment: @MartinSchröder, that actually sounds kind of amazing, do you have any pointer where to look for more info?

Comment: @JuanA.Navarro: Start [here](http://www.mail-archive.com/ntg-context@ntg.nl/msg57499.html).

Comment: Related Question: [Making more easy the itemized of item with tabulation system](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57939/making-more-easy-the-itemized-of-item-with-tabulation-system/57951#57951).

Comment: Curious question - you could use [`pandoc`](http://pandoc.org/) to directly convert Markdown to LaTex...

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Insane answer to an insane question ;)

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\+{+}

\makeatletter
\catcode`\ =12\let\@nl@space= \catcode`\ =10
\newcount\@nl@rlevel
\newcount\@nl@llevel
\@nl@llevel=-1

\def\@nl{%
  \catcode`\ =12
  \global\@nl@rlevel=0
  \futurelet\@nl@store\@nl@%
}
\def\@nl@gobble#1{\futurelet\@nl@store\@nl@}
\def\@nl@enditemize{
  \ifnum\the\@nl@rlevel<\the\@nl@llevel%
    \end{itemize}%
    \egroup%
    \expandafter\@nl@enditemize%
  \else%
    \ifnum\the\@nl@rlevel=\the\@nl@llevel\else%
       \errmessage{Error: inconsistent identation}
    \fi%
  \fi%
}
\def\@nl@{%
  \ifx\@nl@store\@nl@space%
    \global\advance\@nl@rlevel by 1
    \expandafter\@nl@gobble%
  \else%
    \catcode`\ =10
    \ifx\@nl@store+%
      \ifnum\the\@nl@rlevel>\the\@nl@llevel%
        \bgroup%
        \@nl@llevel=\the\@nl@rlevel
        \begin{itemize}%
      \fi%
      \@nl@enditemize%
      \item \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\@gobble%
    \else%
      \ifx\@nl@store\@nl%
        \global\@nl@rlevel=-1\relax\@nl@enditemize\par
      \else\space\fi%
    \fi%
  \fi%
}

\catcode`\^^M=\active%
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \catcode`\^^M=\active%
  \let^^M=\@nl%
}%
\catcode`\^^M=5
\makeatother

\begin{document}
Some sample text.

 + foo
 + bar
   + a
   + b
     + c. A very long line
       split into multiple lines.
 + hehe

Just like nothing happened. Ha!

\+ escaped starting plus

\[\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac1x = 0\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Surprisingly this really works, and it is yet to explode right into my face, therefore, it is stable enough for my needs. :)

Comment: Okay, it seems to play awfully with Babel (at least with the Hungarian one). Replacing the \AtBeginDocument part with a new environment helps, although.

Comment: You really seem to like `@`.

Comment: @MartinSchröder: Better than Knuthian `\nlst@re`, `\nlsp@ce`, etc. :)

Answer (score 16):

You may need to redefine `^^M` to get this feature. That will be somewhat complicated.

As a suggestion, you may use `++` for a subitem, and `+++` for a subsubitem. That's much easier:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\catcode`\+\active
\def\itemX{\@ifnextchar+{\subitemX}{\item}}
\def\subitemX#1{\@ifnextchar+{\subsubitemX}{\subitem}}
\def\subsubitemX#1{\subsubitem}
\def+{\ifmmode\string+\else\expandafter\itemX\fi}
\@makeother\+
\makeatother

\newenvironment{easylist}{\trivlist\item
  \def\item{\par\noindent\textbullet\enspace}%
  \def\subitem{\par\noindent\quad\textasteriskcentered\enspace\ignorespaces}%
  \def\subsubitem{\par\noindent\qquad-\enspace\ignorespaces}%
  \catcode`\+\active
}{\endtrivlist}

\begin{document}

\begin{easylist}
+ foo $a+b$
+ foo 
++ bar
++ bar
+++ baz
+++ baz
+ foo
\end{easylist}

\end{document}
```

See also: [`nicetext`](http://ctan.org/pkg/nicetext) package; [`pandoc`](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/) tool.

Comment: Note: After reassigning the category codes of `^^M` and space char, there is no essential difficulty to distinguish different level of items through indent. However, it is a bit dangerous to redefine newlines and spaces for normal text.

Comment: Oh, finally I realize that there is a package [`easylist`](http://ctan.org/pkg/easylist/), which implement what I said. I just reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 6):

This is a bit different rather use two commands, one to narrow the paragraph and another to widen it. I have used `\i`, `\w`. The first one to make the paragraph narrower (i.e *indent* but lose the dotless i and the second the `\w` for *wider*.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\parskip12pt
\def\narrower{\advance\leftskip by\parindent
\advance\rightskip by\parindent}
\def\wider{\advance\leftskip by-\parindent
\advance\rightskip by-\parindent}


\def\w{\wider}
\def\i{\narrower}

\begin{document}
   \lipsum[1]
   \i \lipsum[2] 
   \i \lipsum[2]
   \i \lipsum[3]
   \w \lipsum[4]
   \w \lipsum[5]
   \w \lipsum[6]
\end{document}
```

Advantages, never type more than is necessary! Style to suit!

Comment: The command \i is already defined. `\expandafter\detokenize\expandafter{\i}`

Comment: @MarcoDaniel ... I know that is why I mentioned you lose the dotless i, you don't need a dotless i do you?

Comment: I didn't read this ;-(. Sorry. Nobody need this ;-) but I thought it is important to mention this.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel No problem, you only need it if you type turkish texts, I picked it for its mnemonics i.e, indent, then the indentation level stays until you change it.

Answer (score 4):

All of the solutions suggested here rely on catcode trickery. LuaTeX provides a sane way to do such input translation. The solution below translates the `+` at the beginning of line to `\firstlevel` and `++` at the beginning of line to `\secondlevel`. So, first lets define the `\firstlevel` and `\secondlevel` macros (in ConTeXt)

```
\define\firstlevel
    {\endgraf
     \blank
     \noindentation
     \hangindent=1em
     \hangafter\plusone
     \dontleavehmode\hbox to 1em {\symbol[1]}}

\define\secondlevel
    {\endgraf
     \blank[none]
     \noindentation
     \hangindent=2em
     \hangafter\plusone
     \null \quad \hbox to 1em {\symbol[2]}}
```

ConTeXt already have a module `m-translate` that allows you to translate the input while the file is being read and before the text is passed on to TeX. So, you can do:

```
\usemodule[translate]
\translateinput[++][\string\secondlevel]
\translateinput[+][\string\firstlevel]

\starttext

+ One
+ Two
+ Three

\enableinputtranslation

+ One, a really long line \input ward
++ Two 
+ Three

\stoptext
```

which gives

[image]

The only trouble is that this translates all the `+` to `\firstlevel`. The `m-translate` module does not provide an interface to only match the character at the beginning of the line, but it is a short module, so we can override how the match is done.

In the following code, I have simply copied the `m-translate` module and changed the `translators.translate()` function.

```
\startluacode
    local translators = { }

    moduledata.translators = translators

    local compiled, list = nil, nil

    function translators.register(from,to)
        local l = lpeg.P(from)/to
        if not list then
            list = l
        else
            list = list + l
        end
        compiled = nil
    end

    function translators.translate(s)
        if list then
            if not compiled then
                compiled = lpeg.Cs((list)^0*(lpeg.P(1))^0)
            end
            return compiled:match(s)
        else
            return s
        end
    end

    local textlineactions = resolvers.openers.helpers.textlineactions

    utilities.sequencers.appendaction(textlineactions,"after","moduledata.translators.translate")

    function translators.enable()
        utilities.sequencers.enableaction(textlineactions,"moduledata.translators.translate")
    end

    function translators.disable()
        utilities.sequencers.disableaction(textlineactions,"moduledata.translators.translate")
    end

    function translators.reset(s)
        translators.enable()
        list, compiled = nil, nil
    end

    translators.disable()
\stopluacode

\unprotect

\unexpanded\def\translateinput
  {\dodoubleargument\module_translate_input}

\def\module_translate_input[#1][#2]%
  {\ctxlua{moduledata.translators.register(\!!bs#1\!!es,\!!bs#2\!!es)}}

\unexpanded\def\resetinputtranslation
  {\ctxlua{moduledata.translators.reset()}}

\unexpanded\def\enableinputtranslation
  {\ctxlua{moduledata.translators.enable()}}

\unexpanded\def\disableinputtranslation
  {\ctxlua{moduledata.translators.disable()}}

\unexpanded\def\readtranslatedfile#1%
  {\enableinputtranslation
   \readfile{#1}\donothing\donothing
   \disableinputtranslation}

\protect

\define\firstlevel
    {\endgraf
     \blank
     \noindentation
     \hangindent=1em
     \hangafter\plusone
     \dontleavehmode\hbox to 1em {\symbol[1]}}

\define\secondlevel
    {\endgraf
     \blank[none]
     \noindentation
     \hangindent=2em
     \hangafter\plusone
     \null \quad \hbox to 1em {\symbol[2]}}

\translateinput[++][\string\secondlevel]
\translateinput[+][\string\firstlevel]

\starttext

+ One
+ Two
+ Three

\enableinputtranslation

+ One, a really long line \input ward
++ Two and math $a + b$ works
+ Three

\stoptext
```

which gives (notice that the + in the math mode has not changed).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had trouble using the previous solutions with beamerposter, so I came up with another.  It's a bit of a kludge, but it works for me, and preserves the bullet styles of the beamerposter:

```
\newcommand{\point}[1]{
\begin{itemize}
\item{#1}
\end{itemize}
}
\newcommand{\subpoint}[1]{
\begin{itemize}
\item[]
\begin{itemize}
\item{#1}
\end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
}
```

Perhaps someone with better code-fu can make this work with active characters instead of my clumsy environment-based way of doing this.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) I think you misread the question, it is about indention in the source.

Comment: Thanks!  As I said, I'm not familiar enough with LaTeX to use the catcode to achieve the desired input syntax.  I was just offering part of a solution (how to make a bullet point of arbitrary depth with a single command instead of a nested list).