# Automatically itemize a paragraph

Tags: macros, lists, paragraphs, itemize

I'd like to use LaTeX for lecture notes but I use bullet lists extensively, and the itemize macro in LaTeX is too time consuming for lecture notes. But if I could teach LaTeX how to do it for me things would be beautiful! (Typing equations in [OpenOffice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenOffice.org) is annoying...)

If I'm typing a regular paragraph in LaTeX, every new line would be bulleted.  There would be a command to denote an item that exists outside the bulleted paragraph. Finally, commands like `\up`, `\down` to promote/demote all lines of text that follow them in the list.

An example:

```
\title{this would be the title of a slide}
this is a line of text
this is another line of text
\up
this is a subpoint
another
\down
last line
```

To get:

> **This would be the title of a slide**
>
> - this is a line of text
> - this is another line of text
>
>   - this is a subpoint
>   - another
> - last line

In a comment below, Werner described this more specifically. I want to "avoid using `\item` for every paragraph, and instead just let the paragraph breaks be "equivalent to" `\item`, while `\up` initiates a new `itemize` environment, and `\down` closes it." `\title` would then close *all* `itemize` environments (the bolding is something I'd like to automatically have done but not necessarily relevant to the question).

Comment: Related: [Using indentation to automatically begin and end itemize environments](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32182/using-indentation-to-automatically-begin-and-end-itemize-environments)

Comment: Related Question: [Making more easy the itemized of item with tabulation system](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57939/making-more-easy-the-itemized-of-item-with-tabulation-system/57951#57951).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm sure there are packages doing this, but probably it's too simple for there to be a dedicated package exactly for this.

Here's a simple solution which probably has to be extended to be really useful.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter

\newcommand\startitems
{%
  \begingroup
  \parindent\z@
  \@itemdepth\@ne
  \@totalleftmargin\csname leftmargin\romannumeral\the\@itemdepth\endcsname
  \leftskip\@totalleftmargin
  \everypar
  {%
    \llap{%
      \makebox[\labelsep][l]
      {%
        \csname labelitem\romannumeral\the\@itemdepth\endcsname
      }
    }%
  }%
  \obeylines
}
\newcommand\stopitems
{%
  \bottom
  \par\endgroup
}

\newcommand\up
{%
  \par
  \begingroup
    \advance\@itemdepth\@ne
    \advance\@totalleftmargin\csname leftmargin\romannumeral\the\@itemdepth\endcsname
    \leftskip\@totalleftmargin
}

\newcommand\down{\par\endgroup}

\newcommand\bottom
{%
  \ifnum\@itemdepth>\@ne
    \down\bottom
  \fi
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section*{title}
\startitems
this is a line of text
this is another line of text
\up
this is a subpoint
another
\up
sub-sub  point
\bottom
back to first level
\stopitems

\noindent Normal text
\end{document}
```

There has to be *some* way to enclose the itemizing effect, so I added `\startitems` `\stopitems`.

[image: example]

Comment: Stephan, this is great.  I have some ideas on how to improve this.  But I'm still brand new to macro writing.  Is there a way to have, for instance, a command `\first` that repeatedly calls `\down` using a while loop or something such that the text succeeding the `\first` command will be on the first level of the list?

Comment: @glifchits As `\down` closes a dynamic scoping level (called group), it is easiest to do this recursively. See my edit.

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to familiarize yourself with one of [lightweight markup languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightweight_markup_language). My favorite is [txt2tags](http://txt2tags.org/). This is how your MWE would look in [txt2tgs](http://txt2tags.org/).

```
How to type LaTeX using txt2tgs
Predrag Punosevac
4/20/2012

                   = This would be the title of a slide =

- this is a line of text
- this is another line of text
 - this is subpoint
 - another 
- last line
```

Now you process your document with the following command

```
txt2tags -t tex myfilename.txt
pdflatex myfilename.tex
```

to get the following output

[image]

It also appears that you want some kind a text presentation program. I really recommend [tpp](http://synflood.at/tpp.html). It is ideal for computer science presentations. It might sound ironic but I used [tpp](http://synflood.at/tpp.html) to give an intro to TeX for absolute beginners.

Comment: I don't think this is what the OP is after. The OP wants to avoid using `\item` for every paragraph, and instead just let the paragraph breaks be "equivalent to" `\item`, while `\up` initiates a new `itemize` environment, and `\down` closes it.

Comment: @Werner that is _exactly_ what I am after.  I would love it if the solution could be built into a new documentclass and I can continue to use TeXworks to write my LaTeX lecture notes.  That being said, Predrag, this sounds interesting and I will be sure to investigate.