# How to detect a tab character when processing a literate in lstlistings?

Tags: listings, characters

In the solution to [Making more easy the itemized of item with tabulation system](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57939/making-more-easy-the-itemized-of-item-with-tabulation-system/57956#57956), I am counting up the number of spaces in order to determine the type of leading character to insert. However, if the I replace the leading spaces with a tab character, the solution does not work.

If I could detect the tab character in the `literate`, then I could have `\ProcessSpace` increment the counter `NumOfContigousSpaces` appropriately, but I don't know how to test for it?

I thought adding `tabsize=4, keepspaces=true` would do the job but this is not quite enough. So I attempted to use `lstag@tabulator` from [How to automatically skip leading white spaces in listings](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19953/how-to-automatically-skip-leading-white-spaces-in-listings/), but was not able to get that to work.

The code below has a 4 leading spaces before the `W` in the first line and a tab as the leading character before the `W` in the second line. This produces no bullet for the line with a tab:

[image]

The correct output can be seen by using 4 spaces before the `W` in both lines:

[image]

### Note:

- It appears the posting a code snippet here replaces a tab with 4 spaces. So to use the MWE below you will need to replace the four leading spaces before the `Wxxx` with a `tab` character.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{listings}

\newcounter{NumOfContigousSpaces}%
\setcounter{NumOfContigousSpaces}{0}%

\newcommand{\Width}{1}%
\newcommand*{\AddApproriateBulletIfFirstChar}[1]{%
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\BulletType}{\arabic{NumOfContigousSpaces}/4}%
    \IfEqCase{\BulletType}{%
        {0}{\gdef\Width{1}}
        {1}{\gdef\Width{3}$\bullet$ }
        {2}{\gdef\Width{3}$\circ$ }
        {3}{\gdef\Width{3}$\times$ }
        {4}{\gdef\Width{3}$\star$ }
        {5}{\gdef\Width{3}$-$ }
    }[\gdef\Width{3}$\bullet$ ]%
    #1%
    \setcounter{NumOfContigousSpaces}{0}%
}%
\newcommand*{\ProcessSpace}{%
    \addtocounter{NumOfContigousSpaces}{1}%
    \space%
}%
\newcommand*{\ProcessTab}{%
    \addtocounter{NumOfContigousSpaces}{4}%
    \space\space\space\space%
}%


\makeatletter
\lstdefinestyle{MyItemize}{%
    basicstyle=\ttfamily,
    columns=flexible,
    tabsize=4, keepspaces=true,
     literate=%
        {\ }{{{\ProcessSpace}}}1% Count contigous spaces
        {lstag@tabulator}{{{\ProcessTab}}}4% ??? how detect a tab?
        %
        %--- much code removed here (See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57939/making-more-easy-the-itemized-of-item-with-tabulation-system for full code)
        {W}{{{\AddApproriateBulletIfFirstChar{W}}}}\Width
        {x}{{{\AddApproriateBulletIfFirstChar{x}}}}\Width
}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[style=MyItemize]
    Wxxx xxx
    Wxxx xx xx
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Using `\^^I` is the 'safe' way to type in a tab, and will let `listings` do the conversion. Unfortunately, there seems to be something up with the width of characters used when `columns = flexible` is set, as the space used for the 'tab' bullet is different from that for the 'four space' bullet.

Comment: @JosephWright: Please make that the answer as I was able to get it to work just fine with that. Required replacing the call to `\ProcessSpace{4}` with a call to `\ProcessTab` which is defined as `\newcommand*{\ProcessTab}{\addtocounter{NumOfContigousSpaces}{4}\space\space\space\space}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `\^^I` is the 'safe' way to type in a tab, and will let listings do the conversion.

Replacing the line using `lstag@tabulator` with the following:

```
    {\^^I}{{{\ProcessTab}}}4%
```

produces:

[image]

(There seems to be something up with the width of characters used when `columns = flexible` is set, as the space used for the 'tab' bullet is different from that for the 'four space' bullet.)

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like:

```
\lstset{
  ...
  tab=$\bullet$\space,     
  showtabs=true,     
  ...
}
```

Comment: I don't want `listings` to replace the tab with a `\bullet` (as that results in two `\bullets` for the case where there are two leading tabs. I want the `\literate` to be able to detect it and treat it as 4 spaces.