# How can I execute some code at each occurence of an EOL character in a listing?

Tags: listings, characters

My question is very similar to Peter Grill's, [How to detect a tab character when processing a literate in lstlistings?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58085/how-to-detect-a-tab-character-when-processing-a-literate-in-lstlistings)

I'm trying to count the number of `^^M` characters encountered in my listing *behind the scenes*, using `literate` as follows:

```
literate={\^^M}{{\ProcessNewline}}1,
```

where the whole purpose of `\ProcessNewline` is to increment a counter **and** insert a `^^M` character (in order to effect a line break in the listing as if I wasn't messing around with `literate` at all).

Incrementing the counter is not a problem, but my attempts at inserting a `^^M` character back have been infructuous. What I think was my best shot is shown in the code below, but I get a `TeX capacity exceeded` error.

What am I doing wrong and what should I do?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}

\newcounter{foo}
\setcounter{foo}{0}

% the following four lines are adapted from Martin Scharrer's lstautogobble package
\begingroup
\catcode `\^^M=\active%
\gdef\activenl{^^M}% Active CR (ASCII 13) ↙character which is used as line break
\endgroup

\newcommand*{\ProcessNewline}{%
    \stepcounter{foo}%
    % \activenl% You'll get an error if you uncomment his line
}%

\lstset{%
    literate={\^^M}{{\ProcessNewline}}1,
}

\begin{document} 
\begin{lstlisting}
one
two
three   
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 for teaching us new words: infructuous - which is not even in my iMac's dictionary...

Comment: @McGafter Now I've got a doubt... Is it an actual word?

Comment: It means unfruitful. http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/infructuous

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}

\newcounter{foo}
\setcounter{foo}{0}

\newcommand*{\ProcessNewline}{%
    \stepcounter{foo}%
}

\makeatletter
\lst@AddToHook{EOL}{\ProcessNewline}
\makeatother


\begin{document} 
\begin{lstlisting}
one
 two
  three   
\end{lstlisting}

[\thefoo]
\end{document}
```