# Increase spacing between item

Tags: spacing, macros, itemize

I am using:

[Automatically itemize a paragraph](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52769/automatically-itemize-a-paragraph?newreg=cb4dc076624148e4b2279a161bbdccc3)

to automatically create `\item` for my bullets and I was wondering how I would go about setting the spacing between each bullet point. The default for the custom `\startitems` command is too narrow.

Comment: It's not using a list mechanism at all just paragraphs, so  add `\setlength\parskip{5cm}` to the definition and the paragraphs will be spaced out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not using a list mechanism at all just paragraphs, so add

```
\setlength\parskip{5cm}
```

to the definition and the paragraphs will be spaced out.