# Possible to create bullets for \subitems using \itemize without a nested list?

Tags: lists, itemize

I have made a list of questions and subquestions using nested `\itemize` commands, like this:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
  \item{First item}
    \begin{itemize}
      \item{First subitem}
      \item{Second subitem}
      \item{Third subitem}
    \end{itemize}
  \item{Second item}
  \item{Third item}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Now this works fine for me, but I am just wondering, could you also create bullets when using `\subitem` instead of a nested list, like below? I do get an indentation at my subquestions, but no bullets.

```
\begin{itemize}
  \item{First item}
    \subitem{First subitem}
    \subitem{Second subitem}
    \subitem{Third subitem}
  \item{Second item}
  \item{Third item}
\end{itemize}
```

Comment: Don't use `\subitem` for this purpose. It's defined only for working in an index.

Comment: I am having the same problem. What is the suggested alternative? Using a nested list, particularly when I only need one sub-item, is a waste of space

Comment: Found package [outlines](http://www.info.ucl.ac.be/~pecheur/soft/outlines.pdf), suits my needs... Hopefully this will help others

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32182/using-indentation-to-automatically-begin-and-end-itemize-environments

Comment: Does my solution no longer answer this question?

Comment: I find your answer satisfactory. That being said, the outlines package does look like an admittedly simpler way to obtain similar functionality.

Comment: @fuzzybear3965: I am not familiar with that package. Please post an answer that shows how to use the package to achieve this as that might be helpful to others.

Comment: @PeterGrill, Done!

Answer (score 48):

An alternative to this approach, which facilitates the production of nested lists is the outlines package. To produce a bulleted list with three levels it is as simple as

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{outlines}
\begin{document}
\begin{outline}
 \1 Top level item
   \2 Sub item
     \3 sub sub item
\end{outline}
\end{document}
```

To make a numbered list (as opposed to a bulleted list) one can simply pass the enumerate option to this package

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{outlines}
\begin{document}
\begin{outline}[enumerate]
 \1 Top level item
   \2 Sub item
     \3 sub sub item
\end{outline}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is a beautifully simple solution, and should be marked as correct

Comment: How could you get dashes instead of bullets for sub items (2nd level)?

Comment: Hey @Mackie I'm not sure as it's been sometime since I used this solution or have written any La(TeX). But, the documentation for this package is at https://ctan.org/pkg/outlines and you may be able to find instructions for using dashes  instead of bullets for unordered lists, there.

Answer (score 23):

While you should *not* use `\subitem`, you can use a different name like `\SubItem` to achieve the desired results with some small hackery. For comparison purposes I put the two lists (one on the right uses `\SubItem`) in a `minipage`:

[image]

### Warning:

- In [this answer to strange interaction between `mdframed` and item](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/47401/4301), egreg mentions that

  > Redefining `\item` can be dangerous and have impredictable results

  I have not seen any issues here, but then I am not an expert on this.

### Code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newlist{SubItemList}{itemize}{1}
\setlist[SubItemList]{label={$-$}}

\let\OldItem\item
\newcommand{\SubItemStart}[1]{%
    \let\item\SubItemEnd
    \begin{SubItemList}[resume]%
        \OldItem #1%
}
\newcommand{\SubItemMiddle}[1]{%
    \OldItem #1%
}
\newcommand{\SubItemEnd}[1]{%
    \end{SubItemList}%
    \let\item\OldItem
    \item #1%
}
\newcommand*{\SubItem}[1]{%
    \let\SubItem\SubItemMiddle%
    \SubItemStart{#1}%
}%

\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.4\linewidth}
    \begin{itemize}
     \item{First item}
      \begin{itemize}
        \item{First subitem}
        \item{Second subitem}
        \item{Third subitem}
      \end{itemize}
      \item{Second item}
      \item{Third item}
    \end{itemize}
\end{minipage}
%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.4\linewidth}
    \begin{itemize}
      \item{First item}
      \SubItem{First subitem}
      \SubItem{Second subitem}
      \SubItem{Third subitem}
      \item{Second item}
      \item{Third item}
    \end{itemize}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'd *never* recommend doing it this way. A nested list is the way to go.

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't see any difference between both lists in your figure. What did I miss?

Comment: @DaniloGregorin: That is exactly the point. The one on the left is produced using a nested list, the one on the right is produced using the `\SubItem` macro defined here, which is what the question was all about.

Comment: Oh, now I see. Got confused with the English, but now I understand. Thank you very much

Answer (score 15):

How about doing something like this?

No need to use additional package, just defining it as a new command. It needs to be in extra brackets, otherwise new indent is applied to all items afterwards.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
%\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\SubItem}[1]{
    {\setlength\itemindent{15pt} \item[-] #1}
}


\begin{itemize}
  \item{First item}
    \SubItem{First subitem}
    \SubItem{Second subitem}
    \SubItem{Third subitem}
  \item{Second item}
  \item{Third item}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

This is the simplest way - no extra packages are needed.

```
\begin{itemize}
      \item{First item}
      \begin{itemize}
            \item{First subitem}
            \item{Second subitem}
            \item{Third subitem}
       \end{itemize}
       \item{Second item}
       \item{Third item} 
\end{itemize}
```

Comment: This is a nested list, which the person who asked the question is trying to avoid.  (Even though it's the method usually recommended.)

Answer (score 3):

I appreciated [fuzzybear3965's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/311843/9057), and I think it could also be modified to this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{outlines}
\begin{document}
  \begin{description}
    \item[An_Item_Which_Should_Be_Displayed_As_Usual]
    \begin{outline}
      \begin{description}
        \item[An_Item_Which_Sould_Be_Indented_Below_The_First_One]
      \end{description}
    \end{outline}
  \end{description}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
\frame{\frametitle{Methodology [Contd.]}
 \begin{itemize}
    \item The Wechsler Adult Intelligence Scale (WAIS-IV) IQ Test was administered to assess students' intelligence. The WAIS, recognized as the most advanced measure of cognitive ability for adults, involved the development of testing software and comprised 5 core subtests and 5 supplemental subtests.
    \begin{itemize}
        \item In the domain of biomedical research, established methodologies, and processes are available for the classification of fingerprint patterns.
    \end{itemize}
    \end{itemize}
}
```

[image]

Comment: Not was this answer already given, but it's also what the original poster didn't want to do.

Answer (score -2):

Simple solution, which gives you flexibility, use the following command: `\subitem $diamond$`. This would allow one to choose any of the math symbols to use in the lists.