# Bullet points and sub bullet points (Items and subitems)

Tags: itemize, bullets

Just having some issues with some items and subitems on latex this is how it looks at the moment:

```
{\begin{itemize}

    {\item \textbf{TEXT}} 
        \subitem {TEXT \textit{TEXT}TEXT}
        \subitem {TEXT \textit{TEXT},$\Phi(\lambda$)  
         \textit{TEXT}}
\end{itemize}
```

It doesnt bring up subitems, It says (! Undefined control sequence.) for each subitem. any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 7):

Just nest `itemize` environments:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
    \item \textbf{TEXT}
          \begin{itemize} 
            \item TEXT \textit{TEXT} TEXT
            \item TEXT \textit{TEXT},$\Phi(\lambda$) \textit{TEXT}
          \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks, i thought i had to state it as a subitem!

Comment: `\subitem` is for indexing; but see: related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84172/possible-to-create-bullets-for-subitems-using-itemize-without-a-nested-list