# Add third level after itemize then list in nested unordered list

Tags: lists, nesting

I have a unordered list with 2 levels in the following form:

```
\begin{itemize}
\item Level 1
      \begin{list}{$\circ$}{}
      \item Level 2
         % Trying  to add a third level here

\end{itemize}
\end{list}
```

I would like to add a third level in this unordered list. Is this possible and if so how do I add another unordered level?

Comment: You could simply nest itemize environments.

Comment: with the outline package -- both numbered and un-numbered lists as below  -- https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/311843/197451

Comment: I wanted to keep the first level as a black circle and the second level as an empty filled circle in the way it is in the example.

Comment: You mentioned the style of bullet points for the first and second level. What about the third level?

Comment: @leandriis The third level can be a black box, or anything really, the reason I care about the first 2 is for continuity with the other things on the document.

Comment: As already mentioned, you could achieve such a list uso g nested itemize environments. The label of each list level can be adjusted individually using the enumitem package.

Comment: the markup should just be three nested itemize environments. latex allows the labels at each level to be specified separately, either just using the core declarations or more easily using the enumitem package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{outlines}
\begin{document}
\begin{outline}
 \1 Top level item
   \2 Sub item
     \3 sub sub item
\end{outline}

\begin{outline}[enumerate]
    \1 Top level item
    \2 Sub item
    \3 sub sub item
\end{outline}
\end{document}
```

edit--

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{outlines}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\setlist[itemize,1]{label=$\triangleleft$}
\setlist[itemize,2]{label=\textbullet}
\setlist[itemize,3]{label=$\circ$}
\begin{document}
    \begin{outline}
        \1 Item 1
        \2 Item 2
        \3 Item 3

    \end{outline}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks @jsbibra, I wanted to keep the circles in the first and second level as is. Could you change this example to do that?

Comment: for global options setlist is the answer -- the circle etc are available through google search -- please the edit above

Comment: in case you find the answer helpful please upvote