# Custom Command for Subitem with Itemize

Tags: itemize, subitem

I found following code from the comments on [Possible to create bullets for \subitems using \itemize without a nested list?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84172/possible-to-create-bullets-for-subitems-using-itemize-without-a-nested-list)

```
\newcommand{\cvSubItem}[1]{%
    {\setlength\itemindent{15pt} \item[{\includegraphics[width=0.3cm]{bullet.png}}] #1}
}
```

Two problems:

1. The first letter of the SubItems has space to the others. It looks like:
   "s pace" instead of "space".
2. If the line breaks, it should start at the same point as the text, not as the bullet:

```
* this happens
if the line breaks
```

```
* this should happen
  if the line breaks
```

!!!UPDATE!!!

I also tried this code for the nested variant:

```
\newlist{SubItemList}{itemize}{1}
\setlist[SubItemList]{label={$-$}}

\let\OldItem\item
\newcommand{\SubItemStart}[1]{%
    \let\item\SubItemEnd
    \begin{SubItemList}[resume]%
        \OldItem #1%
}
\newcommand{\SubItemMiddle}[1]{%
    \OldItem #1%
}
\newcommand{\SubItemEnd}[1]{%
    \end{SubItemList}%
    \let\item\OldItem
    \item #1%
}
\newcommand*{\cvSubItem}[1]{%
    \let\cvSubItem\SubItemMiddle%
    \SubItemStart{#1}%
}%
```

This works well for the first Subitems. But if I have following list:

```
\item
\cvSubItem
\cvSubitem
\item
\cvSubItem
\cvSubItem
```

It only works for the first part.

Thanks for help!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. What's the use case *against* using nested lists?

Comment: I don't think I understand problem 1. For problem 2, look at `enumitem` package. Play around with the `itemindent`  and `listparindent` settings.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. @Mico the template should be as easy as possible for workmates who dont know anything about LaTex.

Comment: I updated my question and tried the nested variant as makro.