# Minimal syntax alternative to enumerate environment

Tags: lists, enumerate, itemize, nesting, markdown

Is there an alternative to the `enumerate` environment in LaTeX where I can define a nested list with a minimal syntax like that of Markdown or something similar, e.g.:

```
\begin{minimallist}
- Fruit
     - Apple
     - Orange
-Vegetable
     - Carrot
     - Tomato
\end{minimallist}
```

Instead of:

```
\begin{enumerate}
\item Fruit
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item Apple
    \item Orange
    \end{enumerate}
\item Vegetable
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item Carrot
    \item Tomato
    \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
```

I don't mind the wordiness of the latter when I'm writing, but it's noticeably less readable for large nested lists, at least for me.

Comment: Is [Using indentation to automatically begin and end itemize environments](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32182/using-indentation-to-automatically-begin-and-end-itemize-environments) what you are looking for?  If so, this question should be closed as a duplicate of that.

Comment: @PeterGrill Yes that's exactly it. Thank you. My question is a duplicate. I should say that I did look for it for a while before writing this one, so perhaps this question is still valuable as most duplicates are to someone searching for an answer.

Comment: Totally agree. I'd definitely recommend _not_ deleting the question, just voting to close it so it gets marked as a duplicate and may help someone else locate the duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this along the lines of what you're looking for?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newcommand{\bmyl}{\begin{enumerate}}
\newcommand{\cit}{\item}
\newcommand{\emyl}{\end{enumerate}}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\bmyl
\cit Fruit
    \bmyl
    \cit Apple
    \cit Orange
    \emyl
\cit Vegetable
    \bmyl
    \cit Carrot
    \cit Tomato
    \emyl
\emyl

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is not what I was after. The duplicate answer link answers it beautifully, but this answer is valuable as well especially in other contexts.