# Default enumerate environment with easylist syntax

Tags: macros, lists, catcodes, easylist

With the package [`easylist`](https://ctan.org/pkg/easylist), we can create nested lists easily:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[at]{easylist}
\begin{document}
\begin{easylist}
    @ First     % -> 1. First
    @@ Second   % -> 1.1. Second
    @@ Third    % -> 1.2. Third
    @ Fourth    % -> 2. Fourth
\end{easylist}
\end{document}
```

It also supports a style looking like `enumerate` with `\begin{easylist}[enumerate]`.
However, it does not use the `enumerate` environment internally; for example, style changes with the package [`enumitem`](https://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) have no effect.

So **is there a way to write nested lists with `easylist` syntax using the `enumerate` environment?**

[This thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/32182) is related and I am looking for a solution mixing [the first answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/32253) (which uses `itemize` internally, but whose syntax is different) and [the second answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/32185) (which has a similar syntax, but does not use `enumerate`) with `+` being replaced by `@`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`easylist` does its own list environment independent of LaTeX's so you can't really integrate one into the other without rewriting pretty much the whole thing.  Here's a different implementation that does only half the job of `easylist`: making `@` mean `\item` and multiple `@` mean nested lists—the half you want.  The new command here, `\easyitem`, does no formatting at all, so the other half, the layout, is left to the surrounding list environment, so you can use the `enumerate` package or `enumitem` or any other you prefer for formatting.

`\easyitem[<char>]` makes `<char>` (which should be one single character, defaults to `@`) an active token that does the list bookkeeping.  `\easyitem` changes the catcode of `<char>` (locally), so naturally the list will not work in the argument to another command (much like a verbatim command).  The `\easyitem` command is supposed to be used inside a list environment, and it will use that same list environment for deeper levels. So

```latex
\begin{enumerate}
  \easyitem[@]
  @ one
  @@ two
\end{enumerate}
```

is equivalent to

```latex
\begin{enumerate}
  \item one
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item two
  \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
```

and if you had used `itemize` or `description` or any other, it would do the same thing with those environments.

Here's the code in a `filecontents` environment, and an example below:

```latex
\begin{filecontents}{easyitem.sty}
\ifdefined\AtEndEnvironment
\else\RequirePackage{etoolbox}\fi
\newcount\easyitem@level
\newcount\easyitem@currlevel
  \easyitem@currlevel=1
\newif\if@ineasyitem
\newif\if@ineasyitemend
\newif\if@easyitembalancing
\newcommand\easyitem[1][@]{%
  \edef\easyitem@char{\unexpanded{#1}}%
  \@ineasyitemtrue
  \global\@easyitembalancingfalse
  \AtEndEnvironment{\@currenvir}{\easyitem@final@balance}
  \expandafter\easyitem@active\expandafter{\easyitem@char}%
  \ignorespaces}
\def\easyitem@active#1{%
  \begingroup
    \lccode`\~=`#1
    \lowercase{\endgroup
  \let~\easyitem@activeitem}%
  \catcode`#1=\active}
\def\easyitem@activeitem{%
  \global\easyitem@level=0
  \easyitem@item}
\def\easyitem@item{%
  \global\advance\easyitem@level by 1
  \futurelet\easy@let\easyitem@count}
\def\easyitem@count{%
  \ifx\easy@let\easyitem@activeitem
    \expandafter\expandafter
    \expandafter\easyitem@item
    \expandafter\@gobble
  \else
    \expandafter\easyitem@do
  \fi}
\def\easyitem@do{%
  \ifcase
       \ifnum\easyitem@currlevel=\easyitem@level 0\fi
       \ifnum\easyitem@currlevel>\easyitem@level 1\fi
       \ifnum\easyitem@currlevel<\easyitem@level 2\fi
       \relax
     \expandafter\item
  \or\expandafter\easyitem@decr
  \or\expandafter\easyitem@incr
  \fi}
\def\easyitem@decr{%
  \expandafter\easyitem@repeat\the\numexpr
    \easyitem@currlevel-\easyitem@level;\easyitem@decr\end}
\def\easyitem@incr{%
  \expandafter\easyitem@repeat\the\numexpr
    \easyitem@level-\easyitem@currlevel;\easyitem@incr\begin}
\def\easyitem@final@balance{%
  \if@ineasyitem \if@ineasyitemend \else
    \global\easyitem@level=1
    \global\@easyitembalancingtrue
    \easyitem@decr
  \fi\fi}
\def\easyitem@repeat#1;#2#3{%
  \ifnum#1=0
    \if@easyitembalancing \expandafter\@gobbletwo \fi
    \expandafter\item
  \else
    \ifx#3\end \@ineasyitemendtrue \fi
    \expandafter#3\expandafter{\@currenvir}%
    \ifx#3\begin
      \advance\easyitem@currlevel by 1
      \ifnum#1>1 \item\relax \fi
    \fi
    \expandafter#2%
  \fi}
\end{filecontents}
```

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{easyitem}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{color}
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label={\color{red}\Roman*}]
  \easyitem[@]
  @ First     % -> 1. First
  @@ Second   % -> 1.1. First
  @@ Third    % -> 1.2. Third
  @ Fourth    % -> 2. Fourth
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

The example above makes:

> [image]

Answer (score 3):

This approach uses `tokcycle` to examine the tokens of the environment without executing them, but adding them to a token list.  If it comes across `@` tokens, it counts the number of contiguous `@` tokens and compares that number to the list level.  If it is greater, it inserts a new level of `enumerate` into the token list, if it is lesser, it ends a level of `enumerate` in the token list.  After any sequence of `@` tokens, `\item` is added to the token list.

At the conclusion of the examination, the constructed token list is inserted into the environment.  A closeout `\end{enumerate}` is provided.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{environ,tokcycle}
\newcounter{listlevel}
\newcounter{atcnt}
\Characterdirective{%
 \ifx @#1
  \stepcounter{atcnt}\gdef\atcounting{T}
 \else
  \if T\atcounting
    \ifnum\value{atcnt}>\value{listlevel}\relax
      \stepcounter{listlevel}%
      \addcytoks{\begin{enumerate}}%
    \else
      \ifnum\value{atcnt}<\value{listlevel}\relax
        \addtocounter{listlevel}{-1}%
        \addcytoks{\end{enumerate}}%
      \fi
    \fi
    \setcounter{atcnt}{0}%
    \gdef\atcounting{F}%
    \addcytoks{\item #1}%
  \else
    \addcytoks{#1}%
  \fi
 \fi
}
\NewEnviron{easylist}{%
  \setcounter{listlevel}{0}%
  \expandafter\tokcyclexpress\expandafter{\BODY}%
  \the\cytoks\end{enumerate}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{easylist}
    @ First     % -> 1. First
    @@ Second   % -> 1.1. Second
    @@@ next level a   % -> 1.1. Second
    @@@ next level b   % -> 1.1. Second
    @@ Third    % -> 1.2. Third
    @ Fourth    % -> 2. Fourth
\end{easylist}
\end{document}
```

[image]